# Looking for a replayable / somewhat stateless PRNG algorithm

Tags: algorithm, prng

I'm looking for a pseudo-random number generator that is "replayable" and "stateless". Let me elaborate: I need to be able to re-fetch a pseudo-random number based on a parameter to the random function. For example (C-style pseudocode):

```
int x1 = random(1);
int x2 = random(2);
// and so on with lots of random() calls in between
int new_x1 = random(1);
// now new_x1 is like a "replay" of x1, so x1 == new_x1
```

The type of arguments doesn't matter (I can typecast whatever is needed), the return value doesn't have to be `int`; ultimately I'll need 8-bit values.

The question is: what's a good PRNG algorithm that satisfies the requirement that the next pseudo-random value is controlled by a parameter, and not by its internal state which is updated upon each invocation? I don't what to use a crummy solution like the following:

```
int random(int input) {
    srand(input);
    return rand();
}
```

This would have to initialize the PRNG upon every invocation, which seems costly. (I am illustrating this point using the standard `srand() / rand()`, I know there are better algorithms out there, like Mersenne Twister, but the idea is still the same.)

Comment: Are you sure you are not just looking for a hash function?

Comment: Why do you think that srand is costly? It literally just sets the seed for the PRNG.

Comment: @ChrisHeald, because e.g. the Mersenne Twister algorithm initializes 624 states upon seeding. Seems overkill to do that just to fetch one next pseudo-random number.

Comment: @kingkero, interesting idea.. I'll think about it, maybe with a supplied prefix salt that acts as the seed.

Answer (score 0):

One approach that might work here would be to use a block cipher like AES or triple-DES. Your pseudorandom generator could then be

```
int pseudorandomValue(int input) {
    return encryptUsingAES(input);
}
```

This is stateless, pseudorandom (since the outputs of AES should be statistically indistinguishable from random), and stateless.

Hope this helps!

Comment: EDIT: Upon deeper contemplation in utter silence, I think that using AES or 3DES won't do the job. Reason is that `encryptUsingAES(1); encryptUsingAES(1);` will yield 2 different values, since AES is state-aware. Right?

Comment: @KarelKubat AES is not stateful, so encrypting two values with the AES block cipher itself (not using a random IV) should always produce the same output.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the Xorshift[1,2] based PRNG. This PRNG uses the previous random number to generate the next. The implementation is very efficient, as compared to AES.

For 32-bit implementation:

```
uint32_t next_rand(uint32_t prev)
{
   prev ^= prev << 13;
   prev ^= prev >> 17;
   prev ^= prev << 5;
   return prev;
}
```

For 64-bit implementation:

```
uint64_t next_rand(uint64_t prev)
{
   prev ^= prev << 21;
   prev ^= prev >> 35;
   prev ^= prev << 4;
   return prev;
}
```

The random number sequence is "replayable", stateless, and depends on only the initial value, which is the seed.

References:

1. Wiki:[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift).
2. A paper with detailed math: [paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v08/i14/paper).

Comment: Very nice and looks absolutely fast.